# Excel check that value in column is always matches the column next to it

Tags: excel, compare, match

I need to run a match but am unsure how  to do it this particular way.

I have a sheet with thousands of ID numbers for each employee in column A

I then have a unique UID string in column B.

I need to make sure that every time value x shows up in column A the value next to it in column B is the same.

So if I have

1234   0987
1234   0987
1234   0988

It will flag the 0988 since 1234 is supposed to always have the same value to the right of it

Comment: Are your values always going to be in order? Or could you have the line `9876 1234` in between `1234 0987`?  Also, do you have the list of ID and UIDs? In other words, how do you know `1234` should be `0987` instead of `0988`?  The solutions below are just pointing out where the UIDs don't equal the ones above in the column, but if you can know ahead of time what the UID for each ID should be, you can search for the incorrect UIDs only.

Comment: I will always have it sorted by ID and then UID so that is fine. The real probl;em I am facing is more that there are inconsistencies with their IDs and UIDs so I get a LOT of false positives.  Not much I can do there beyond a full script that breaks each ID down one at a time and has exceptions for any known false positives.

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edited to respond to question from OP]

Sort columns A, B and C (containing exceptions) using column A as the first key and column B as the second key. Then in column D in the second row of data (e.g. C2) put a formula like:

```
=IF(C2="Exception", "OK", IF(A2=A1,IF(B2=B1,"OK","BAD"),"OK"))
```

and fill down to the end of your data.

A more succinct version is:

```
=IF(C2="Exception", "OK", IF(AND(A2=A1,B2<>B1),"BAD","OK"))
```

You can then search by values for "BAD". Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you think of any way to add an exception?  Like if there is say, a 3rd column that says oh I don't know, "Exception" it would report as OK?  :)

I suppose it may be easier for a two step approach in that case  


Edit: Oh, also, that worked perfectly by the way

Comment: I just looked it over and the exceptions thing wont actually work for me anyway.       

I am dealing with a massive list(80K+) of users for a z/OS mainframe and their UIDs and IDs are all over the place in terms of formatting :(

Comment: This is as close to 100% as I think I can get without VBA.  Thank you for your response and the update, both worked exactly as they should.

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional formatting on the second column and make sure that every row below the first is equal to the first.

E.g:

```
=b2=b$1
```

Comment: OP has to make sure his data is sorted first, in order.